# Program in CL (IBM i series) that retires library objects?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, control-language

I have four libraries where each has a different selection of a set of programs. Unfortunately i cannot delete the unused programs in the library with SQL, since i need to retire them (so they don't stay on our clients servers).

Is there a way to make a CL program for this? Our senior programmer says that it cant be done, but i want to explore every possibility before being forced to manually retire 2300 objects.

It is originally a function within Aldon change management software and I do have a SQL query for selecting the objects needed.

Comment: What do you mean by retire if not delete?

Comment: It's better if you say more explicitly what "retire" means.  Don't make people guess or have to research it.  Not everyone is familiar with Aldon.  What do **you** have to do when **you** retire an object manually?  What does it entail?  Moving stuff to other libraries?  Putting stuff into save files?  What?

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess it's too late to help the original poster, but for future reference...

"Retire" is a concept used by the Rocket Aldon Lifecycle Manager for IBM i,  aka Aldon LM(i).  A change management system (CMS) for the IBM i.

Note that most if not all the Aldon screens respect the standard IBM i UI function of F13-Repeat, to fill the option field of all subfile records with the same value.

So, check out all the objects to a single task. Using the ACMSCHKOUT or ACMSADDPJO commands if you want.

Then it's simply a matter of going into the Work with Objects screen for the objects on that task, putting an option 25-Retire of the first object and pressing F13-Repeat to repeat the option for all objects then just hitting enter.

Promote and deploy the task as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the difference between retire and delete in your context but here is a sample CL to read a file of program objects and delete them.

It assumes as input a file named **DLTFILE** with the fields **LIB** and **PGM**.

```
PGM

DCLF FILE(DLTFILE)
LOOP: RCVF RCDFMT(DLTFILE)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF0864) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(BREAK))
DLTPGM(&LIB/&PGM)
GOTO CMDLBL(LOOP)

BREAK: ENDPGM
```

Comment: Retire function is a feature from Aldon's Lifecycle management system. This question may be harder then i thought.

Comment: If Aldon has a 'retire' API, you could use James' program to call that instead of DLTPGM.

Comment: here is a link to the Aldon documentation.  I didn't find the API, but maybe if you look around, you can find something. http://myaldon.rocketsoftware.com/psup/dnlds/doc/aldon-lifecycle-manager-IBM-i/